# Can the archimedian postulate prove the limit of the series $1/n$ is $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

So I know that the sequence $a_n = 1/n$ will converge to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.
By the definition of a limit this means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ in the naturals such that for all $n\geq N$, $|1/n - 0|<\epsilon$ and this can be proved using the Archimedian postulate, since a $N$ can be found s.t $N>1/\epsilon$ this is all well and good and makes sense.

But the problem comes up if I were to guess the limit wrong and say tried to prove that $1/n\to 1$ as $n$ approached infinity. This would mean showing $|1/n - 1|<\epsilon$ which can also be done using the Archimedian postulate as an $N$ can be found s.t $N>1/(\epsilon+1)$. I don't understand how they can both be proved as the second is clearly untrue.

Comment: Sequence, not series.

Comment: "which can also be done using the Archimedian postulate"

No it can't. What makes you think that it can? 

"an N can be found s.t N>1/(ϵ +1)."

This is not the Archimedian postulate.

Comment: Take $ε = 1/3$. Check if you can find any $N$.

Comment: Is it not the case that if i rearrange (1/n - 1)<$\epsilon$ then i get n>(1/($\epsilon$)+1) the archemedian postulate says i can find and N in the naturals such that N>(1/($\epsilon$)+1) and then just choose n>N?

Comment: In case the distinction isn't clear, an infinite series is more likely to be an infinite sum.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This is the *sequence*, not the *series*. (These are two different things).
2. Let's do as you suggest: fix any $\varepsilon > 0$. Indeed, as you point out there exists an integer $N$ such that, for all integers $n\geq N$, $$
   n \geq N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon+1}\,.
   $$
   This is true. But what does that give? It is equivalent to
   $$
   \forall n \geq N, \qquad \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon+1
   $$
   itself equivalent to
   $$
   \forall n \geq N, \qquad \frac{1}{n} - 1  < \varepsilon
   $$
   This is true, but is **not** the same as
   $$
   \forall n \geq N, \qquad \left\lvert \frac{1}{n} - 1\right\rvert  < \varepsilon
   $$
   since $\frac{1}{n} - 1$ can (and will) be negative...

**In short:** you forgot to worry about the *absolute values.*

Answer (score -1):

You appear to have used the supposed identity $|1/n-1|<\epsilon\iff|1/n|<\epsilon+1$

But this is not a correct identity because the absolute value of $1/n-1$ measures that $1/n$ moves away from $1$ as $n$ increases, despite $1/n-1$ itself being negative for all $n>1$.

Therefore pulling the $-1$ out of the absolute value function exchanges the sign of the part within, so for the identity to hold you would need to exchange the signs elsewhere.